# Idle / Stale Gerrit SSH Connection cannot be closed

Tags: ssh, gerrit

We're having idle/stale ssh connections in Gerrit 2.11.7. When running

```
ssh -p 29418 git.example.com gerrit show-connections
```

We see many connections with an idle time over 1 minute (up to 20 hours at the moment):

```
Session     Start     Idle   User            Remote Host
--------------------------------------------------------------
c8da2d6d 10:58:26 21:32:14   user            ?
a838199a 10:59:55 21:30:46   user            ?
088da5bb 11:10:24 21:20:16   user            ?
48c87df6 11:14:50 21:15:49   user            ?
88f4354c 11:16:37 21:14:02   user            ?
28d429cd 11:21:36 21:09:04   user            ?
6d5f93b4 11:31:17 20:59:23   user            ?
cbcb2ba3 08:00:51 00:29:49   user            ?
90ad64cb 08:30:42 00:00:00   user            10.x.x.x
```

According to the documentation it should be possible to close this connections with:

```
ssh -p 29418 git.example.com gerrit close-connection cbcb2ba3 --wait
```

When we try this command, nothing happens and the only option is to cancel the operation with CTRL+C. The connection stays present/idle.

(I've also submitted a bug report for this: https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=4044)

Comment: Stiil an issue with gerrit v3+.

I wrote an extended version of Gerrit v2.13 where the connection pool items were 'killable', like the task pool. I also extended the 'show-connections' admin command to enumerate the connection's task ID and connection time, and a script to show the 'hung' connections to allow an admin to nuke stale/untimed-out entries.

If my current employer grants me time I may rebase those changes onto the newer Gerit version and publish that change back to Google. But not before December this year.